# Xubuntu won't boot after I turn off machine

Tags: xubuntu

For some reason, whenever I turn off my computer and turn it back on, it won't boot into the OS. It just seems to hang on a black screen. But when I restart the computer after that it turns on and works normally, what am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you have Windows 8 previously ? (I mean UEFI or BIOS)

Comment: No, I did not. I had Windows 7 before

Comment: Model and Specs of your PC please !

Comment: Try just pressing a few keys or clicking the mouse when the black screen comes up.

Comment: AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor, 16GiB RAM, GeForce GTX 660, M5A78L-M/USB3 Motherboard

Comment: I did try moving my mouse and typing keys on the screen, nothing happened.